# Fetching File From a WebApp Folder in a Non-Servlet Class (Java/Tomcat)

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

I am trying to fetch a few XSD files from a webapp that I built using maven. The folder structure is something like this:

```
DAC (WebApp)
    WEB-INF/
    META-INF/
    xsdFiles/
    xmlFiles/
```

Now I am trying to fetch a file from the `xsdFiles` folder. The only thing is its not a servlet class. But somehow nothing seems to work. I tried `getResource()`, `getResourceAsStream()` or just trying to fetch the files using `Paths.get("/xsdFiles/theXSD.xsd")`.

I would assume that item put under the resource folder wouold be available in the classpath, wouldn't it? This is my maven entries:

```
<resources>         
    <resource>
        <directory>./src/main/resources/xmlFiles/</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/xmlFiles/</targetPath>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>./src/main/resources/xsdFiles/</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/xsdFiles/</targetPath>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

And my WAR Plugin:

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <addDefaultEntries>true</addDefaultEntries>
                <addBuildEnvironmentEntries>true</addBuildEnvironmentEntries>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                <classpathPrefix>WEB-INF/lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        <classesClassifier>shared</classesClassifier>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <includeEmptyDirectories>true</includeEmptyDirectories>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/lib</outputDirectory>
        <webResources>
            <webResource>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/xmlFiiles/</directory>
                <include>**/*</include>
                <targetPath>xmlFiiles/</targetPath>
            </webResource>
            <webResource>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/xsdFiles/</directory>
                <include>**/*</include>
                <targetPath>xsdFiles/</targetPath>
            </webResource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please paste here what you tried with getResource() and getResourceAsStream ?

Comment: @rootkonda I tried all of these options, all of them return null
`InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/xsdFiles/sampleTable.xsd");
   inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xsdFiles/sampleTable.xsd");
   
   URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader.getResource("/xsdFiles/sampleTable.xsd");
   url = this.getClass().getClassLoader.getResource("xsdFiles/sampleTable.xsd");`
I normally dont like to fiddle around with class loaders, but if this is the only way, I have to stick with it.